# After porting a non-VoIP number to Twilio - is it a VoIP or a non-VoIP number?

Tags: sms, voip

If I port my T-Mobile prepaid non-VoIP number to Twilio, will I still be able to use that number to authenticate online accounts such as Airbnb and Facebook?
...or will it no longer work since web-services will see it as being VoIP?

As you may know more and more websites today block users from registering VoIP numbers.

Does anyone know the logic of how a number get vetted? Meaning when a number is authenticated (by Facebook for example), does it check the number in real-time if its VoIP or does it check to see if the number was originally created as VoiP?